# Can I use $q.all in AngularJS with a function that does not return a .promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

If I have the following functions:

```
   doTask1: function ($scope) {
       var defer = $q.defer();
       $http.get('/abc')
           .success(function (data) {
               defer.resolve();
           })
           .error(function () {
               defer.reject();
           });
       return defer.promise;
   },

   doTask2: function ($scope) {
       var defer = $q.defer(); 
       var x = 99;
       return defer.promise;
   },
```

I'm told that I can wait for both promises like this:

```
    $q.all([
            doTask1($scope),
            doTask2($scope)
    ])
        .then(function (results) {

        });
```

How about if task 2 does not return a promise? I saw in the $q documentation 
for AngularJS that there is a "when". However I am not clear on how to use it
and there's no example.

Is it the case that I MUST have doTask2 return a promise by having the two lines:

```
var defer = q.defer()
return defer.promise
```

or is there an easier way to do this?ll

Comment: Why would you need $q.all if doTask2 doesn't return a promise.  You only need $q all if you want to wait until all the included promises are resolved.  If you just want to run a synchronous function do it after the $q.all promises are resolved.

Comment: @Geoff - I was giving that as an example. I have quite a few functions and doTask2 or something similar would just be one of them. Putting all those functions inside the $q.all makes it look clear and makes it obvious that they all need to finish even if one of them such as doTask2 would finish immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### $q.when is used in scenarios where you don't know upfront whether the function is returning a promise or a direct value.

The following example/plunker shows a method, whose result is used in $q.all, and which returns different type of object (int or promise) every time it's called:

<kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnTQ7Tta5tp0K9zPM502?p=preview)**</kbd>

```js
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $q, $http) {
  var count = 0;

  function doTask1() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('abc.json')
      .success(function (data) {
        defer.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function () {
        defer.reject();
      });
       
    return defer.promise;
  }

  /**
   * This method will return different type of object 
   * every time it's called. Just an example of an unknown method result.
   **/
  function doTask2() {
    count++;
    var x = 99;
    if(count % 2){
      console.log('Returning', x);
      return x;
    } else {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      defer.resolve(x);
      console.log('Returning', defer.promise);
      return defer.promise;
    }
    
  }
  
  $scope.fetchData = function(){

    // At this point we don't know if doTask2 is returning 99 or promise.
    // Hence we wrap it in $q.when because $q.all expects 
    // all array members to be promises
    $q.all([
      $q.when(doTask1()),
      $q.when(doTask2())
    ])
      .then(function(results){
        $scope.results = results;
      });
      
  };
  
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MainController'>
  <button ng-click="fetchData()">Run</button>
  <pre>{{results|json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

> is there an easier way to do this [than manually constructing and resolving a deferred and returning a promise]?

Yes, use the [`$q.when` function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#methods_when):

```
doTask2: function ($scope) {
    return $q.when( 99 );
},
```

However, you don't actually need to do this. [`$q.all`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#methods_all) will - though not stated in the docs - also work with non-promise values (implementation [calls](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/98b2f8ef18cd3024e566252d4537075cb3e4a24b/src/ng/q.js#L496) [`_ref`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/98b2f8ef18cd3024e566252d4537075cb3e4a24b/src/ng/q.js#L333) which converts it). So just

```
return 99;
```

is fine as well. However, if you know beforehand that it's synchronous, using promises doesn't seem to make much sense.