# How angular interceptors works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was learning angular interceptors today. I did some samples to to better understand the concept. Here is small sample.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory("timestampMaker", [
  function() {
    var timestampMaker = {
      request: function(config) {
        console.log(config);
        config.requestTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        return config;
      },
      response: function(response) {

        response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        return response;
      }
    };
    return timestampMaker;
  }
]);

app.config(['$httpProvider',
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timestampMaker');
  }
]);

app.run(function($http) {
  $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/naorye/repos').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var time = response.config.responseTimestamp - response.config.requestTimestamp;
    console.log("The request took" + (time / 1000) + "seconds")
  });
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

</html>
```

When I am doing `console.log(config)` inside request function, here is the output on the console.
[image]

I am not getting how `responseTimestamp` appear in the config object of request where as  its defined inside response function

Answer (score 0):

**Note** I used the source code for 1.2.x which is the one added in the question.

`$httpProvider` is a provider that gives you `$http` service.

As a provider, in config time exposes a public array - there you just add all strings from services names you wanted to be injected in your response/requests.

That is what you do here

```
app.config(['$httpProvider',
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timestampMaker');
  }
]);
```

and it can be only done in config time because per [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe) providers can be configured before the application starts

You can see the exposed array in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L159) in line 159

```
var responseInterceptorFactories = this.responseInterceptors = [];
```

When you request the `$http` service, injecting it into your service/controller, 
`$get` function is executed. In that function, your array of interceptors is iterated, as you can see in [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L179) in line  179

```
   var reversedInterceptors = [];
   forEach(responseInterceptorFactories, function(interceptorFactory, index) {
      var responseFn = isString(interceptorFactory) ? $injector.get(interceptorFactory) : $injector.invoke(interceptorFactory);

      /**
       * Response interceptors go before "around" interceptors (no real reason, just
       * had to pick one.) But they are already reversed, so we can't use unshift, hence
       * the splice.
       */
      reversedInterceptors.splice(index, 0, {
        response: function(response) {
          return responseFn($q.when(response));
        },
        responseError: function(response) {
          return responseFn($q.reject(response));
        }
      });
    });
```

Per convention, they reverse the order. You can see that using the string, they get a reference to the function using `$injector.get` or `$injector.invoke`, and using `$q.when()` we can introduce them to the promises chain, even if they are synchronous code - See this [Can I use $q.all in AngularJS with a function that does not return a .promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774011/can-i-use-q-all-in-angularjs-with-a-function-that-does-not-return-a-promise) if you are not sure what I meant about `$q.when()`

So far we have an array with functions, which are all promise-like (thanks to `$q.when()`). When you request data through `$http` like this

```
$http.get('https://api.github.com/users/naorye/repos').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var time = response.config.responseTimestamp - response.config.requestTimestamp;
    console.log("The request took" + (time / 1000) + "seconds")
  });
```

even though you have the `.get()`, is just a shortcut for all the same functionality which is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/http.js#L716)

In the code the relevant part is this one:

First, a chain array is created with two values: an inner function which is not important for our purpose (but it returns a promise - this is important), and undefined value.

Our array with interceptors is iterated, and request interceptors are added at the beginning (before the request) and response at the end. Like this

```
   function serverRequest {
      // some code
    };
     var chain = [serverRequest, undefined];
    var promise = $q.when(config);

    // apply interceptors
    forEach(reversedInterceptors, function(interceptor) {
      if (interceptor.request || interceptor.requestError) {
        chain.unshift(interceptor.request, interceptor.requestError);
      }
      if (interceptor.response || interceptor.responseError) {
        chain.push(interceptor.response, interceptor.responseError);
      }
    });
```

then, having the chain complete (remember our array of interceptors was full of promises), the code iterates it, adding all of them using `.then()`, causing all of them to be executed in a chain, following promises chaining (you can google that)

```
    while(chain.length) {
      var thenFn = chain.shift();
      var rejectFn = chain.shift();

      promise = promise.then(thenFn, rejectFn);
    }
```

Finally, the callback you add in `success` and `error` is added at the very end of the chain and the promise is returned

```
 promise.success = function(fn) {
  promise.then(function(response) {
    fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
  });
  return promise;
};

promise.error = function(fn) {
  promise.then(null, function(response) {
    fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
  });
  return promise;
};

return promise;
```

The only part I am not sure about is the use of `undefined` in the chain array

**Summary**

You add the name for your services, `$HttpProvider` uses `$invoke` service to get them and adds them in the promise chain using `$q.when()`, returning a promise. At the end of that, your callbacks for a specific `$http` request is added.